# How to fire a keyup event from outside an input field in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have created a card component in Angular:

```
<div class="my-card" (keyup.enter)="onUploadButtonClick()">

  <div class="img-container">
      <img src="path-to-image"/>
  </div>

  <div class="my-card__form">
    <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
      <label>First Input:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="input1">

      ...

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to achieve the following: Whenever I have clicked into the card, upon hitting the Enter key, I want to call `onUploadButtonClick()`. It is partly working correctly already: When the focus is on one of my input fields, upon hitting the Enter key, the `onUploadButtonClick()` method is called. However, it seems that the keyup event can only be fired from within an input field. I would like to fire this event as well when I have previously clicked onto my card, but my current focus is not on an input field. Is there a way to achieve this? Also: What I don't want is to fire this event whenever I hit Enter anywhere inside my application, only when I have previously clicked onto the card.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on the question, but it seems you want `keyup` events to trigger from non `input` elements in the component

You'll need to make those elements focusable to register keyboard events. Try adding `tabindex="0"` to the div(s)

Comment: this seems to be working as well! I run into an issue with my form validation though, since I perform form validation onBlur only. With your solution uploading my form upon Enter will only be possible if I am focussing on my div, which is fine since in that case form validation works fine. However, I thought maybe there is a way to allow for uploading on Enter as well if I am focussed on an input field. In order to enable form validation I will have to lose this focus though upon hittin Enter. It might not be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to listen the keyup event globally in your component by using  @Hostlistener. Check this https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#description

You will need a property in your component to save the last div clicked, base on that you could invoke **onUploadButtonClick()** or not

Comment: this seems to be working! The only issue is that when I am still focussed on one of my input fields, the form validation is not executed. I perform form validation onBlur only. So, I have created an onEnter() method, which calls `uploadButton.nativeElement.focus()`, where the `uploadButton` is a ViewChild. Afterwards I call `onUploadButtonClick()`. But the focussed input field does not seem to lose focus and, hence, form validation is not executed.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you should save the information whether the user has previously clicked on the card:

add a flag for that information into your controller:

```
public userHasClicked = false;
```

add logic to switch userHasClicked to true when the user clicks on the card:

```
<div class="my-card" (keyup.enter)="onUploadButtonClick()" (click)="userHasClicked=true">
    ...
</div>
```

add a check for that flag before executing the code insude `onUploadButtonClick()`:

before:

```
onUploadButtonClick() {
    // your code
}
```

after:

```
onUploadButtonClick() {
    if (this.userHasClicked) {
        // your code
    }
}
```